# HTML table: Matching the height of a row to the height of another row

Tags: html, html-table, row

I have an HTML table with two rows. These two rows currently wrap to fit the content. I want the top row to continue to change its height to fit the content of the row, but I want the second row (which would otherwise have a lesser height) to match the height of the top row. How would I do this?

Even better would be for the top or bottom row to match the height of whichever row has the greatest height. However, I don't know whether this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this using pure html/css.  You would have to script it with javascript.